# rails directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, io

I have rails project and want to load all files from directory. I started it like ""rails c but it says that

```
No such file or directory
```

Here is example of my code:

```
class ParserPlugin < ApplicationController
  def self.loadPlugins
    a = File.new("1234")
    Dir.foreach("/plugins") do |f|
      if f != '.' and f != '..'
        load("/plugins" + f.to_s)
      end
    end
  end

  def self.createplugin
    @@plugins << self.new
  end
end
```

File structure is

```
  /home/andrii/LV-081/app/controllers/admin/plugins
```

Can you give me any advice?

Comment: What happens if you execute this command on the command line: `ls /plugins`

Comment: What does your current file structure look like?

Comment: Why? This doesn't look very Rails-like.  Why ParserPlugin is inheriting form ApplicationController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read files from `/plugins` directory, not from `plugins` subdirectory of `app/controllers/admin`. Try this:

```
Dir.foreach(Rails.root.join("app", "controllers", "admin", "plugins")) do |f|
  if f != '.' and f != '..'
    load(Rails.root.join("app", "controllers", "admin", "plugins", f.to_s))
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file is probably located here: /app/controllers/ParserPlugin.rb

The directory you're trying to print is here: /app/controllers/admin/plugins

By saying this:

```
Dir.foreach("/plugins")
```

Rails thinks there is a /plugins folder in the current working directory (/app/controllers/plugins)

I would try logging something like `Dir.getwd` (get current working directory) to see where Rails thinks you are, and then access your files from there.

You should try using Rails.root though: `Dir.foreach(Rails.root.join('app', 'controllers', 'admin', 'plugins'))`